# Baofang uv-5rA/ repeater trouble

Tags: receiver, baofeng, repeater

I programmed my Baofang UV-5RA radio to my local repeater about less than a 1/4 mile away. When I cue the mic and release, I get a signal from the repeater. However, I can only hear people if I have the moni button pressed. They can hear me clear but I can’t hear them unless I press the moni button.

I also have another baofang uv-5ra radio that I set up to the same repeater, and I can’t transmit to it from my other baofang radio. Same thing happens I have to press the moni button and I can barley hear it.

I programmed my radio to a repeater in San Francisco and I heard them loud and clear.

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Did you program your radio with software, or did you do it from the front panel of the radio (ugh)?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you programmed a receive tone requirement. Try programming only the transmit tone and leaving the receive tone not required.

I don't have Chirp available right now so I can't give you the names of these fields.

Best, 
Ed Greenberg
KM6CG